# "How a foolish boy he is!" vs. "How foolish a boy he is!"

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice

- How a foolish boy he is!
- How foolish a boy he is!

Which one is more correct?

Actually I think it's the first one but I am not sure.

Comment: The first one would be correct with a small change to "What a foolish boy he is!" but as it is, the second is 'more correct' with its inversion.

Comment: How a foolish boy gets into trouble. How to hold your fork.

Answer (score 1):

*How* is used in this kind of sentence only with adjectives and adverbs, so only the second can be grammatical.

With a noun phrase, we use *What a* instead, eg *What a foolish boy he is*.

If the sentence is about a noun, then we use the *what a* construction even if it is a quality (eg "foolish" that is being wondered at). So *What a foolish boy he is* is **much** more idiomatic than *How foolish a boy he is*.

Answer (score 0):

If the choices are these two sentences:

> 1. How a foolish boy he is!
> 2. How foolish a boy he is!

#1 is completely wrong.
#2 sounds strange, but not "completely wrong".  It's questionable.

Better choices would be:

> 3. What a foolish boy he is.
> 4. Let me tell you, how foolish he is. Very foolish.
> 5. That boy... is so foolish!
> 6. He is certainly a foolish boy.
> 7. How foolish the boy is, to think he could trick me.

Comment: #2 is not really “questionable”.  Grammatically, it’s perfectly correct, it’s just an uncommon usage.  The version “ What a foolish boy he is” is virtually the same except you are using the noun form instead of the adjective.

Comment: Just curious, are there are any native speakers of US English reading this who would use sentence #2 in everyday speech or writing?

Comment: — word for word, no, if only because “foolish” has fallen out of favor.  You will hear similar constructions like “How stupid do I feel” “How lucky that win was.”

Comment: @Malvolio ... "fallen out of favor".  It's more than only that. Swap out "foolish" for "stupid".

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is incorrect grammatically. The second sentence is correct, but very formal and some would view it as old-fashioned. In some contexts, however, it would be natural.

Source: I have seen similar syntax used in English translations of the Qur'an.

The most natural choice for a casual conversation, in my experience, would be "What a foolish boy he is!"

Answer (score 0):

Colin Fine has given a fine answer. But it does not fully address Sam’s point that the second sentence sounds odd. I agree with Fine that “how foolish a boy he is” is less idiomatic than “what a foolish boy he is.” But

> How foolish that boy is

strikes me as fully idiomatic. In other words, the structure “how adjective indefinite article noun is” is off key whereas “how adjective specified noun is” is not off key.

> How stupid that was

may not be as common as

> What a stupid thing to do that was

but few would find the first strange.

**EDIT**: I agree as well that “foolish” is no longer a fashionable word in American English. That does not affect the grammatical and structural issues, but it adds to the oddity of the example.